# Linking different android activities from buttons in main menu

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm absolute beginner in Android apps development.

I created a main menu with buttons. Lets say, the buttons are named *btnA*, *btnB* and *btnC*. From main menu, if I click on *btnA*, then I will be linked to *AsActivity*. Similarly, from main menu, if I click on *btnB*, I will be sent to *BsActivity*. It is the same as *btnC*.

I have totally no idea on how to do that. Thank you.

Comment: Post some code where you have defined the buttons. I mean are they in /menu/menu.xml or where??

Comment: Please post some code of your MainActivity and it's layout.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`Intent`](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=intent%20in%20andorid&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html&ei=l66IUOWeN5SgiQf2pICAAw&usg=AFQjCNEjqM87rUmTERzSDN9d4ltsHw3kxQ&cad=rja) to move from home page to any activity on button click

```
  BtnA.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent n = new Intent(Home.this,actA.class);
            startActivity(n);
        }
    });

    BtnB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent n = new Intent(Home.this,actB.class);
            startActivity(n);
        }
    });

    BtnC.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent n = new Intent(Home.this,actC.class);
            startActivity(n);
        }
    });
```

And also add actA,actB and actC to manifest file

Comment: It gives me errors when I type in the name of the button (ie. btnA). Do I need to declare anything? And what does _Home_ means?

Comment: yes you need to declare a buttons. first of all read [android dev](http://developer.android.com/index.html) for better knowledge on basics

Comment: [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/how-to-switch-between-activities-in-android/) link may help you.check it

Comment: Thanks! The link helps! But I still don't get wad is the "Home" in `Intent n = new Intent(Home.this,actA.class);` Can you explain a bit? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Home is the activity name where your all buttons reside.